# How to get Bool from Cursor (Java SQLite)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, boolean, android-sqlite

So for example if I do a table like

```
db.execSQL("create table myTable (" + "id integer primary key autoincrement," + "title text," + "isImportant numeric" + ");");
```

and want to get "title", I do

```
String result;
Cursor c...;
int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");
do
  ...
  result = c.getString(titleIndex);
  ...
while (c.moveToNext());
```

Same with c.getInt, c.getDoule, etc. But there is no c.getBoolean. So how can I get value of "isImportant" from that table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `getBoolean()` method because [there is no Boolean data type in SQLite](https://sqlite.org/datatype3.html#boolean_datatype) (although you can define a column as Boolean).

If you have stored the values in the column as `0` or `1`, then you can retrieve boolean values like this:

```
String result;
boolean isImportant;
Cursor c...;
int titleIndex = c.getColumnIndex("title");
do
    ...
    result = c.getString(titleIndex);
    isImportant = (c.getInt(isImportantIndex) == 1);
    ...
while (c.moveToNext());
```